# I tried several times to get two styles for same activity on the same page but it doesnt work

Tags: css, stylesheet

I need "orange" color to my hyperlinks only one one specific page. there is already a .css file designed for other pages. Now how can i tell html to design links in a different way only for one page. No matter whatever I experiment, it picks up style from the included .css file. Please tell me how to write a different links style only for one specific page of a website. Thanks...

These are the three methods  I tried

```
a:link { color: orange;}
a:visited {color: orange;}
a:hover {color: orange;}
a:active {color: orange;}

div.nav a:link, div.nav a:visited, div.nav a:hover, div.nav a:focus, div.nav a:active 
  { 
  color: orange; 
  }

a.nav1:link,a.nav1:visited,a.nav1:active
  { 
  color: orange; 
  }
```

EDIT: Its not working. Let me explain it again.
Assuming i have three files with dark background color, header.php, one.php and two.php. CSS styles are set for all these three files.... and link, visited, hover, focus and active all colors are white.

Now I have a new file three.php with a white background color.. so the link gets hidden. Actually it is there but since the link style color is white and page background is also white, it is not visible. I want to make this orange.

When I did that, in the css file, all previous three files links color changed from white to orange. all link color in the header file changed from white to orange.

How can i keep orange color link (ink, visited, hover, focus and active everything) only in the new fourth page without changing hyperlinks color of the other files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a wrapper to this specific page and named it for example `<div id="specificPage"></div>` This wrapper need to wrap all content you create on this page.

After that just add `#specificPage` to your CSS decalartions:

```
#specificPage a:link { color: orange;}
#specificPage a:visited {color: orange;}
#specificPage a:hover {color: orange;}
#specificPage a:active {color: orange;}

#specificPage div.nav a:link,#specificPage div.nav a:visited, #specificPage div.nav a:hover, #specificPage div.nav a:focus, #specificPage div.nav a:active 
{ 
    color: orange; 
}

#specificPage a.nav1:link, #specificPage a.nav1:visited, #specificPage a.nav1:active
{ 
    color: orange; 
}
```

You can also declare a specific class. For example class `orange` for your `a` tag. In your CSS it would be something like this:

```
.orange {
    color:orange;
}
```

All you need to do now is to add this class to your hyperlinks in your HTML structure.

---

Example:
`<a href="#" class="orange">LINK</a>`

Comment: Thanks but nothing seems to be working out or I may not be able to understand. In my project, there are lot of 4 css files involved and I am lost somewhere in linking. I want to ask you a question. If I want to use the above style that you gave me, can i add it in < a href tag? so that only that particular link takes this style?

Comment: Are you able to modify HTML in your fourth page? Just add `orange` class to your `<a>` tags there as i suggest in my answer - `<a href="#" class="orange">LINK</a>`. Or just wrapp all content on your fourth page with a `<div>` tag and add `id="specificPage"` to it. Of course don't remember to add CSS declarations as i mentioned above.

Comment: I understood your solution Kamil but i dont know why it was not happenning. the orange class option and wrapper options both are working now. I dont know how everything got changed. I am assuming that it could be cache problem. I cleared temp files, cache, cookies and it worked. Thank you for your support